# Using data from multiple cameras

Tags: data-acquisition, hardware

`ImageCapture[]` has an option `Device->` for specifying which camera to use, but `CurrentImage[]` takes no options and no relevant arguments. Changing `$DefaultImagingDevice` might or might not work, but it would be a pretty awkward solution for a program that needs to frequently take frames from different cameras quickly.

Is there a way to use `CurrentImage[]` with more than one camera? If not, is there a better workaround?

Comment: Take a look here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2772/193

Comment: I'm actually using that function now on a different application on Linux; I was wondering if there was a better workaround than just rewriting that function into taking an argument to pass to cvQueryFrame().

Fortunately, I'm familiar with OpenCV.